# How to stop a sprite from bouncing off a specific surface

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hi I am making a endless scrolling game where the character basically avoids obstacles as they come and he can jump over them. I got everything to work pretty well but I see that the character texture will bounce slightly after hitting the ground. I want the sprite to stop immediately after touching down. I tried setting the .restitution property to 0 but i still see it bouncing. Here is the setup code for my stickman character and the edge physics category in question

```
stickman.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    stickman.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    stickman.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    stickman.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Stickman
    stickman.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge
    stickman.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Obstacle | PhysicsCategory.Edge
    stickman.physicsBody?.restitution = 0


self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: playableRect)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge
```

Where playable rect is just the screen boundary for universal deployment purposes.

Has anyone run into this problem. I couldn't quite find the same issue in other posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `restitution` of the physics body your sprite is running into to `0` as well. Both physics bodies in a physics collision need to have a restitution of 0 to result in no bounciness.

Comment: No problem! The documentation doesn't make it obvious. Remember to accept the answer when it allows you :)